# How to render a pyramide with each row by level property?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

```
array (

   array(

     ['name'] => 'test1',
     ['level'] => 1

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test2',
     ['level'] => 2

   },

   array(

     ['name'] => 'test3',
     ['level'] => 2

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test4',
     ['level'] => 3

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test5',
     ['level'] => 3

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test6',
     ['level'] => 3

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test7',
     ['level'] => 3

   },



)
```

I have an array of arrays sorted by level, thus I want to make something like this:

```
                  ________  
                 |        | 
                 |  test1 | 
                 |________| 
       ________              ________
      |        |            |        |
      |  test2 |            |  test3 |
      |________|            |________|
 ________   ________   ________   ________
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|  test4 | |  test5 | |  test6 | |  test7 |
|________| |________| |________| |________|
```

render them like a pyramide each row by level, but first how do I render it by using recursion or using a while loop? to make each level wrapped by `<ul>` and the nodes by `<li>`

I'am trying to render it by loop, but I don't know how, what is the logic?:

```
    while ($item = $this->dbtree->NextRow()) {

        $rows[] = (object)$item;

    }
    print_r($res); // list of arrays like the above
    exit;
```

thanks for attention

Answer (score 0):

You can first iterate over the array and sort them in to the levels in your application logic:

```
foreach ($res as $resValue){
    if (!isset($levelSorted[$resValue['level'])){
        $levelSorted[$resValue['level'] = array();
    }
    $levelSorted[$resValue['level'][] = $resValue;
}
```

In your view you can now do something like this:

```
foreach ($levelSorted as $level => $levelRes){
    echo '<ul id="level' . $level . '">';
    foreach ($levelRes as $singleRes){
        echo '<li>' . $singleRes['name'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

At the end, you have more than one loop, but it would be consistent with the MVC pattern.